# linq to sql catching error without breaking loop, but can't clear previous errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

i am trying to read data from sql file, the sql file has 4000 lines,
so i loop each row and inject it to database with LINQ to SQL,
but the problem is some of my sql data has redundant values, 
while my database field has unique constraint i.e "email" field, 
so i tried to catch error that occurs and add it to exception list
without breaking the loop,

```
 importDataContext imp = new importDataContext();

 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\go_data_applicant (1).sql");

 List<Exception> loopExceptions = new List<Exception>();

 user_list usr = new user_list();

 foreach (string line in lines)
 {
     var txt = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      idx += 1;

      if (txt.Length == 49)
      {
         if (txt[24] != "")
         {
                 try
                 {
                      usr = new user_list
                      {
                            email = (txt[24].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            second_email = second_email,
                            password = (txt[2].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            fname = (txt[5].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            mname = (txt[6].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            lname = (txt[7].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            birthday = parsed_date,
                            birthplace = (txt[9].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                            id_no = (txt[29].Replace("'", "")).Replace(" ", ""),
                            id_valid_to = valid_to,
                            modified_date = DateTime.Now,
                            created_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt[46].Replace("'", "")),
                            language_pref = "ind",
                            status_user = 1,
                            user_type = "user",
                            managed_by = "self",
                            expected_salary = salary
                       };

                         imp.user_lists.InsertOnSubmit(usr);
                         imp.SubmitChanges();

                  }
                  catch (Exception er)
                  {
                      loopExceptions.Add(er);
                      imp.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, usr); // i tried this
                  }

            }
        }
        else
        {
              throw new Exception ("index : " + idx + " , total length : " + txt.Length);
        }            
    }
```

the problem here is once the error occurs because of redundant data, my data context keep injecting the same data, so i did this to refresh my data context

```
 imp.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, usr);
```

i also tried this :

```
   imp.Dispose(); // did not work either, causing another error.
```

but it did not work. oh btw i can't fix my sql file manually, coz it has 4000 lines, so the only option is to handle it throught code.

Comment: I would suggest you move your `SaveChanges` out of the loop. No need to call it every time

Comment: i did that before, but my file has 4000 lines, if error happens, i have to wait for loop to stop before i can see the errors, so i modified it.

Comment: if you want to break out of the loop - just type `break;`. Perhaps you should *validate* the input berfore submitting to the database?

Comment: no, i don't want the loop to break, instead i want it to continue reading the line and injecting to database, what i want to achieve is ignoring lines with redundant data i.e 'email' field

Comment: @JensKloster ur comment just give me an idea to prevent error to happen, thanks!